# How to authorize GitHUb API

Tags: github, google-api, dart

Does anyone know how to authorize GitHub API in developers.google.com? I could not find GitHub API in the API List. Could anyone tell which URL I need to fill in the blank to use as the scope parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: The GitHub API is not controlled by Google so you have to create an app with [GitHub](https://developer.github.com/).

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is not a Google product. Checkout [GitHub's API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) for this.